# Masonry-like unordered list only css

Tags: css

I've heard of masonry, I've heard of CSS3 columns, I would like to know if I can simply use an unordered list to generate a masonry-like grid or layout.

Consider the following: I have a list with eight items. Each row has four items and has an unknown height. If the list items are displayed as an inline-block, the next row will be pushed down if an item from the upper row contains a larger height.

The result is this:

[image]

You see how the second row is pushed down? I would like only the first item to be pushed down while the rest remains in place.

Desired Outcome: [image]

Here's the demo list:

```
<ul>
    <li style="height:125px;"></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li>This should be pulled up to maintain the margin bottom</</li>
    <li>This should be pulled up to maintain the margin bottom</</li>
    <li>This should be pulled up to maintain the margin bottom</</li>
</ul>
```

---

```
ul {
    list-style: none;
    font-size: 0; /** inline-block hack **/
}

ul li {
    font-size: 14px;
    
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top; 
    
    margin-right:  calc((20px / 3) - 5px);
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    
    height: 100px;
    width: calc(25% - 5px); 
    border: 1px solid #222;
    
}
    
ul li:nth-child(4n + 4) {
   margin-right: 0; 
}
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/f9fhxrta/2/)

Answer (score 2):

if you don't want the list elements to be ordered horizontally, I can help. You could use columns for it.

You want to wrap your list in a container and use `column-count` on it.

I recently wrote a [codepen](https://codepen.io/bekreatief/pen/uzsDm) using that technique to create the masonry effect.

If you want a gap just change the cap-property for the gabs between the rows, for the top and bottom just add margins to the list elements.

Answer (score 0):

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

ul {
  display: block;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  -moz-column-width: 13em;
  -webkit-column-width: 13em;
  -moz-column-gap: 1em;
  -webkit-column-gap: 1em;
}

li {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li style="height:100px"></li>
  <li style="height:200px"></li>
  <li style="height:50px"></li>
  <li style="height:150px"></li>
</ul>
```